# Spring security login gives error page, is authentication failing?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to spring security (security in general) and I am trying to create a user login that goes to a products page when successfully logged in. Following all the tutorials I have come across in regard to the security configuration, I keep getting "login?error" and I cant figure out why, I cant pinpoint it in the debugger.

I am using Postgresql and have tables user, role, user_role. I have verified my sql statements for jdbcAuthentication and have configured the .formLogin many different ways

Below is my web security configuration, login controller, and login view.
Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

**SpringSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // Database authentication
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, active FROM \"user\" WHERE username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.username, r.role FROM \"user\" u join user_role ur on (u.userid=ur.userid) join role r on (ur.roleid=r.roleid) WHERE u.username = ?");

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/products","/mycart","/images/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successForwardUrl("/products")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

**LoginController.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginView(Principal principal) {

        return "/login";
    }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">

        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                Incorrect Username and Password
            </div>
        </div>

        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                User Logged Out
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btm btm-primary btn-block" value="Login"/>
        </div>
    </form>

    <a href="/registration">Register</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your run console, or any other tool you are using to execute this?

Comment: No errors or warnings in IntelliJ console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine but you need to add "name" attribute to your inputs like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" required="true" autofocus="true"/>
</div>
```

Second, check that you have encoded your password with BCryptPasswordEncoder in database (or first try without an encoder and setting a plain password)..

In another way try to submit a sample project in github and maybe I can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ariel! I needed a fresh pair of eyes. Once I added the name attribute I saw this post method wasn't being provided by spring so I also changed a few things in my security configuration and now login works wonderfully. Thanks again!